# alter table drop column syntax error using sqlite

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, alter-table

This is the schema of my table:

```
create table LPCG(ID integer primary key, PCG text, Desc text, test text);
```

I wish to drop the column "test", and hence use the command:

```
alter table LPCG drop column test;
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Error: near "drop": syntax error
```

Can someone please help me correct my error?

An additional question is: I understand that ID is the primary key attribute. Would I be able to drop that column? If not, is there a workaround which anyone has used?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Up to version 3.35, [SQLite did not support `ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN` statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html). You could only rename table, or add columns.

If you want to drop a column, your best option was to create a new table without the column, and to drop the old table in order to rename the new one.

As of now, ALTER TABLE support is still limited but includes dropping a column, under conditions.

Comment: `DROP COLUMN` is supported in recent releases of Sqlite - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66399224/5320906)