# websql drop column with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm trying to delete a column in a websql database with javascript.  I have tried the following with no success:

```
db.transaction(
    function(transaction) {           
        transaction.executeSql('ALTER TABLE log_entries DROP COLUMN name;');
    }
);
```

where, name is the column I want to delete from the table log_entries.

Could someone please advise me how I would go about deleting a column in a websql database with javascript?

Comment: Is websql returning any error messages?

Comment: I think there should be no ';' after name within the single quotes

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite .

Answer (score 1):

In the Web SQL is not implemented removing fields. 
I'm currently working on this problem. One of way - data dump and remove the table. Then restore the table with the new fields. Restore the data from the dump