# SQL ALTER DROP query not working

Tags: sql, alter, sql-drop

I am learning `SQL` online from [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/).

for droping a column
 `ALTER TABLE table_name 
 DROP COLUMN column_name` command is given in [SQL ALTER](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) page

i tried it in [Try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all) section provided by w3school.
but it's not working

I used

```
ALTER TABLE Customers
DROP COLUMN City;
```

I also try to do this query on  [compile online/sql](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_sql_online.php).
but again it's not working.

so, can any one explain me where i am wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it's not working" ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please include any error messages, exact details of what does or does not happen.  Leave nothing out.  We can only see what you show us.

Comment: Please do not use w3school.com for learning languages!

Comment: it shows  Error1: could not prepare statements(1 near "DROP":syntax error);

Comment: I think w3schools wont let you delete a column,the syntax is fine.Just install something like xampp adn practice offline.

Comment: Please tell us which DBMS you are using? Postgres? Oracle? Firebird?

Comment: i don't know , i am learning and practicing it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice what it says in the brackets?

`To delete a column in a table, use the following syntax (notice that some database systems don't allow deleting a column)`

See the answers to these questions:

[websql drop column with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108204/websql-drop-column-with-javascript)

[How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

W3schools uses websql. Try [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4d4e1/1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
    use 'DatabaseName';
    ALTER TABLE Customers
    DROP COLUMN City;
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'try it yourself' link you provided seems to be set up for testing a 'Select all' statement.  It may not be a fully functional environment, and you may not have permission to run all statements.