# I have four columns in an sqlite table and I want to delete data of three columns and keep the data of other one

Tags: sqlite

I have four columns in a table. I am using sqlite database and I want to delete data of three columns and keep the data of other one column.

```
String sql="DELETE  january,deducted,remaining FROM sailary where id=?";

try
{
    pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
    pst.setString (1, jut.getText());
    pst.execute();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: You can't delete columns from a single row. Do you want to remove/reset the *values* of the columns in a particular row, or do you want to remove those columns from the entire table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is used to remove **rows**. What you could do is `update` these columns to be `null` in the specific row you're referring to:

```
UPDATE sailary
SET    january = NULL, deducted = NULL, remaining = NULL
WHERE  id = ?
```