# Is there an easy way to drop UNIQUE attribute from an SQlite table column?

Tags: sqlite

Is there an easy way to drop UNIQUE attribute from an SQlite table column?

I've googled and it says I am to create a same structure table without UNIQUE, copy the data, then drop the old table, then rename the new table to the old name.

While I can do that, I wonder if it can be done easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the accepted answer on this link:
[How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147)

It seems like SQLite removes a lot of the ALTER TABLE functionality that would **usually** let you do those kinds of operations in "regular" SQL.