# Rails Migration Error - StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rails-migrations

> Using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.2, OSX 10.10

I initially added a migration to my Movies table.

```
rails g migration addFieldsToMovies
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20150616125848_add_fields_to_movies.rb
```

Then migrated to the database:

```
rake db:migrate
== 20150616125848 AddFieldsToMovies: migrating ================================
-- add_column(:movies, :description, :description)
   -> 0.0006s
-- add_column(:movies, :release_date, :datetime)
   -> 0.0003s
== 20150616125848 AddFieldsToMovies: migrated (0.0009s) =======================
```

I then realized I put the wrong data type on the description field. So I created a migration file like:

```
rails g migration change_description_type_in_my_table
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20150616130929_change_description_type_in_my_table.rb
```

I added the `change method` to the migration file `20150616130929_change_description_type_in_my_table.rb` to edit the field type to text:

```
class ChangeDescriptionTypeInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :movies, :description, :text
  end
end
```

I then:

```
rake db:migrate
== 20150616130929 ChangeDescriptionTypeInMyTable: migrating ===================
-- change_column(:movies, :description, :text)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:258:in `column'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:544:in `block (2 levels) in copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:537:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:537:in `block in copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:202:in `create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:534:in `copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:527:in `move_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:520:in `block in alter_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:519:in `alter_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:483:in `change_column'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Users/username/Documents/projectname/db/migrate/20150616130929_change_description_type_in_my_table.rb:3:in `change'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I attempted to rollback the database like [this SO Answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159963/standarderror-an-error-has-occurred-this-and-all-later-migrations-canceled-whe):

```
rake db:rollback
== 20150616125848 AddFieldsToMovies: reverting ================================
-- remove_column(:movies, :release_date, :datetime)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:258:in `column'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:544:in `block (2 levels) in copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:537:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:537:in `block in copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:202:in `create_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:534:in `copy_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:527:in `move_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:520:in `block in alter_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:519:in `alter_table'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:462:in `remove_column'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:497:in `block in revert'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:496:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:496:in `revert'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:604:in `exec_migration'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:827:in `down'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:907:in `move'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:809:in `rollback'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:125:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Some SO answers suggest it is a SQLite 3 issue, but I doubt it because the rollback error would not occured (I believe).

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634557/on-migration-undefined-method-to-sym-for-nilnilclass

Comment: If you edited the generated migration file, as you mentioned here "I added the change method to the migration file 20150616130929_change_description_type_in_my_table.rb to edit the field type to text:..." all bets are off. Those files are like breadcrumbs.

Comment: I'd delete your new migration file, run `$ rake db:rollback` to rollback the last migration and then edit the AddFieldsToMovies migration.

Comment: So I deleted the new migration file and rolled backed, but the db was not modified. So I manually deleted the columns with a SQLite GUI... Now I check the status 
` Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150615152925  Create movies
   up     20150616125848  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20150616142250  Add fields to movies`

How do I get rid of that *** NO FILE ***

Comment: Never mind just found out. I'm back on track again. Thanks everyone.