# How to delete a column from requery.io db in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, orm

I have a table defined as:

```
@Table(name = "Rooms")
@Entity
interface IRooms : Persistable {
    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    @get:Key
    var roomJid: String

    @get:Column(name = "gameId", nullable = false)
    @get:ManyToOne
    var game: IGames

    @get:Column(name = "creatorJid", nullable = false)
    @get:ManyToOne
    var creator: IProfiles

    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    @get:OneToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeAction.DELETE, CascadeAction.SAVE))
    val players: MutableList<IPlayers>

    @get:JunctionTable
    @get:ManyToMany(cascade = arrayOf(CascadeAction.DELETE, CascadeAction.SAVE))
    val invitedContacts: MutableList<IInvitedContacts>

    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    var lastModified: Long

    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    var isLocked: Boolean

    var nextPlayerJid: String?

    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    var hasGameEnded: Boolean

    @get:Column(nullable = false)
    var isSoloRoom: Boolean
}
```

What I want to do is to delete `isSoloRoom` column and add another column `matchType` defined as:

```
@get:Convert(MatchType.RequeryConverter::class)
var matchType: MatchType?
```

Now, I want to write migration script to remove `isSoloRoom` column and if `isSoloRoom` value is `True` set `matchType` to **SOLO** else `null`.

What I tried:

1. I removed `isSoloRoom` column from the Schema above and in `onUpgrade` method I wrote:

`db?.execSQL("UPDATE Rooms SET ('matchType') = ('SOLO') WHERE soloRoom = 1")`

The `matchType` column is successfully added with desired effect but `isSoloRoom` is not removed.

What should I do in order to remove the `isSoloRoom` column and add `matchType` column. Should I remove it from Schema too and from `onUpgrade` script too via sqlite (which would be very hectic to write entire create table) or does requery provides some alternative to it?

Comment: I don't know why you are programming like this. It looks REALLY old school. Change your style grandpa lol (joke). I'd suggest you use the Android SQLite "norm" .... Create you `contract` class ; update it at will... Create EVERY SINGLE `create` table statement.. I know it's painful but you know what !? ... When you'll encounter situations like yours, you'll love to just change DB_VERSION so that `onUpgrade` does the job

Comment: That seriously isn't cool and does not answer the problem.

Comment: oooo I'm sorry. Did not mean to hurt you... Actually, you can't drop a column with SQLite https://stackoverflow.com/a/8442173/6266949 No matter what method you think of, if you want to remove a column in SQLite, just backup what ever you want, Then drop the table. Recreate it with a new structure and restore backup information...Sorry again..