# How to drop a non-key column without deleting related records with Sequelize Migrations?

Tags: database, sqlite, migration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am currently about to learn how to use Sequelize migrations. Therefore I created some example models and migrated them as well. No I tried to delete a column - the migration works fine for that as long as I had no data inserted.

So here are my example models:

```
Model1 {id:int, name:string, description:string, fk_model2:int {references Model2:id} } 
Model2 {id:int, name:string, description:string, test:string}

Model1toModel2 {id_model1:int, id_model2:int} //not a real model but a table
```

There is a 1:n relation between *Model1* and *Model2*, and an n:m relation, too. 
The n:m relation is represented in the database with a table and is created by it's own migration.

Now there is this problem: 
I defined a column named *test* in table *Model2* (as shown). After I inserted some example data, I tried to run a migration, which deletes this column. On table *Model2* this works just fine.

First try: I used `onUpdate: 'cascade', onDelete: 'cascade'` in *fk_model2*-column in table *Model1* when creating the tables in a migration file. 
So the *delete-column* migration emptied the *Model1* table and the *Model1toModel2*-table which was created for the n:m relation. That is not what I want.

Second try: I used `onUpdate: 'cascade', onDelete: 'restrict'`. As expected this gives me `ERROR: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` as I now cannot delete *Model2*-data that is used in *Model1*. Also this is not what I want.

**Question**: If I migrate a table, does it delete the whole record and recreates it according to the new conditions defined in the migration file? - so the `ON DELETE`-Condition fires?

How could I achieve that it just deletes the column *test* which is not a key value, without touching the tables *Model1* and *Model1toModel2*? (Of course, if the key (& therefore the whole record) in *Model2* is deleted, I want the records in *Model1toModel2* to be deleted, too, and the 1:n in *Model1* to be set `NULL` or `DEFAULT`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem/solution here:
[How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite)

Sequelize only pretends to drop a column, instead of this it deletes the data and recreates it afterwards as expected. So this causes the related records to drop or throw SQL-Errors.