# How do i roll back this rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I ran the below migration and forgot to include the default value I wanted.  I'm trying to roll it back so that I can add the default and roll it forward again.

20190728151635_add_cooldown_to_skill_levels.rb

```
class AddCooldownToSkillLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :skill_levels, :cooldown, :integer
  end
end
```

All rails db:migrate and db:rollbacks are failing with the below error

$ rails db:rollback

```
== 20190728151635 AddCooldownToSkillLevels: reverting =========================
-- remove_column(:skill_levels, :cooldown, :integer)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "skill_levels"



And 100+ more lines ...
```

I've tried changing the migration to have explicit up/down methods to no avail

```
class AddCooldownToSkillLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def up
    add_column :skill_levels, :cooldown, :integer
  end

  def down
    remove_column :skill_levels, :cooldown
  end
end
```

I've tried adding a new migration that just adds the default value.

20190728153208_add_default_value_to_cooldown_on_skill_levels.rb

```
class AddDefaultValueToCooldownOnSkillLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_column_default :skill_levels, :cooldown, 1
  end
end
```

Similar error
$ rails db:migrate

```
== 20190728153208 AddDefaultValueToCooldownOnSkillLevels: migrating ===========
-- change_column_default(:skill_levels, :cooldown, 1)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "skill_levels"

And 100+ more lines ...
```

I'm comfortable fixing it directly in SQL, but I'm trying to keep my migrations intact.

edit: adding output of $ rails db:migrate:status

```
...
   up     20190727160901  Create skill levels
   up     20190728004535  Create skill effects
   up     20190728151635  Add cooldown to skill levels
  down    20190728153208  Add default value to cooldown on skill levels
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a real database for development, postgres would be my choice but mysql is good too.

Comment: The issue appears to be related to how sqlite handles ALTER TABLE commands. I didn't prove this out, but I believe the solution can be found here: [sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) in the "Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes" section. The process looks painful.

Comment: Already installing pg.  Lost 1/2 a day on this mess.  thank goodness for unit tests.

Comment: Good for you, I wish the Rails team would stop using sqlite as a default database, there is question after question about problems with this here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The error:

```
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "skill_levels"
```

is telling you that there is a foreign key constraint that references your `skill_levels` table (i.e. `t.references :skill_levels, foreign_key: true` in some other migration) and the `remove_column :skill_levels, :cooldown` is causing a problem with that.

But why would a database constraint be a problem during an ALTER TABLE to remove a column? Well, SQLite's ALTER TABLE [doesn't support removing a column](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11), instead you have to (see the SQLite FAQ or [How to delete or add column in SQLITE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8442147/479863)):

1. Create a new table without the column that you're removing.
2. Copy the data to the new table.
3. Drop the original.
4. Rename the copy.

ActiveRecord does this behind the scenes for you. Step (3) is where things are going wrong because you can't drop a table that is being referenced by foreign key constraints. I think you'll have handle the foreign key by hand: first use separate `up` and `down` methods, then modify the `down` method to:

1. Drop all the foreign keys that reference your table, you can use [`remove_foreign_key`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-remove_foreign_key) for this once you know what FKs you're dealing with.
2. Then `remove_column :skill_levels, :cooldown` as you have now.
3. And finally put all the FKs back, you can use [`add_foreign_key`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key) for this.

Something like:

```
def down
  remove_foreign_key :some_table, :skill_levels
  remove_column :skill_levels, :cooldown
  add_foreign_key :some_table, :skill_levels
end
```

Ideally ActiveRecord would take care of this for you but presumably AR's SQLite support is mostly from before AR supported foreign key constraints.

Comment: No luck.  I even added a commit after removing the FKs and then started a new transaction for (what is essentially a table drop) column removal.  The FKs all drop successfully but then it fails with the same error.  From some additional research this appears to have a very convoluted 12 step process to resolve because of how sqllite handles ALTER TABLE.  I'm throwing in the towel and nuking the DB and running $ rails db:setup again.  That should get me back into a good place in dev and test and production is still behind this migration so I should be okay.  Thanks for your help.