# SQLITE syntax error code 1 when renaming a column name

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax, migration, rename

I am migrating a Room database in my Android app. This is the migration code:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE item RENAME itemInfoId TO itemId");
    }
};
```

The error message

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "itemInfoId": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE item RENAME itemInfoId TO itemId
```

I have also tried the SQL of `"ALTER TABLE item RENAME COLUMN itemInfoId TO itemId"`, same error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "COLUMN": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE item RENAME COLUMN itemInfoId TO itemId
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename keyword is available in SQLite version 3.25 which is not available for the latest android version. You will have to manually upgrade the table

**1.** Create item_tmp table with correct column value itemId

```
CREATE TABLE item_tmp(<column1> <data_type>, itemId <data_type>,.....)
```

**2.** Copy the data from item to item_tmp

```
INSERT INTO item_tmp(<column1>, <column2>,..) 
    SELECT <column1>, <column1>, ... 
    FROM item;
```

**3.** Drop table item

```
DROP TABLE item;
```

**4.** Rename the item_tmp table

```
ALTER TABLE item_tmp RENAME TO item;
```

Comment: I saw the same question from 2018 I think. I would have thought that this would be fixed by now. Any tips on manually upgrading the table? I already had to do it once with 20 records, it wasn't a big problem but doing it again would be quite tedious and in the future there will be hundreds of records.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Note that the order of operations in this answer is one explicitly called out as incorrect in [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Shawn and user2864740. I have updated the answer please verify.

Comment: Is there perhaps a generic way to do it? Some like what I see on removal of columns, as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51587449/878126

Comment: I am getting this issue with SQLite version 3.32.2 2020-06-04 12:58:43

Comment: The second step is incorrect. It should be `INSERT INTO item_tmp SELECT FROM item`.

Answer (score 2):

i have faced same problem while using RENAME keyword in Sqlite.
it gives error in below android 10 device and working perfectly in android 11 and above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this issue, I am facing the same problem. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: You have to write the complete migration script for the room database. Renaming the field needs a lot of steps.

Comment: I'll share a migration script if you need it

Comment: I am using SQLite, and this same problem exists even on Android 13. I want to know if this problem is fixed or not.