# Simple SQL question: where is the syntax error?

Tags: sql, sqlite, ddl, create-table, alter-table

```
sqlite> .schema autor

CREATE TABLE autor (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NOME TEXT, CIDADE TEXT, ESTADO TEXT, TELEFONE TEXT, idade number);

sqlite> alter table autor drop idade;

Error: near "drop": syntax error
```

(Also tried to use DROP COLUMN instead of DROP).
Please help, is that a bug ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442147/how-to-delete-or-add-column-in-sqlite

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I didn't know about that. Already tried to delete the question but I'm not allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with SQLite, because it does not support dropping columns. This is [a documented limitation](https://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html) (emphasis mine):

> Only the `RENAME TABLE`, `ADD COLUMN`, and `RENAME COLUMN` variants of the `ALTER TABLE` command are supported. Other kinds of `ALTER TABLE` operations such as **`DROP COLUMN`**, `ALTER COLUMN`, `ADD CONSTRAINT`, and so forth are omitted.

A possible workaround is to recreate another table with the correct structure, then copy the data, drop the old table and rename the new table:

```
create table autor_new (
    id integer primary key, 
    nome text, 
    cidade text, 
    estado text, 
    telefone text
);
insert into autor_new select id, nome, cidade, estado, telefone from autor;
drop table autor;   -- back it up first!
alter table autor_new rename to autor;
```